# Objective-C Mac-App Top bar

Tags: objective-c, macos, navigation, widget

I'm currently looking for a widget for Mac OSX apps, which looks like this one:
[image]

I have seen such "top bars" in many apps, so i thought there should be a widget out there, but I haven't found anything about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an [NSToolbar](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Apple has a couple different examples showing how to create a toolbar and add items to it: [SimpleToolbar](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimpleToolbar/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008817) and [ToolbarSample](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ToolbarSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000413). Items like those found in iTunes require custom views inside the toolbar items.

Comment: Thank's a lot! That's exactly what i was searching for.